# How to set the color of a barchart / barchartseries?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

does anyone know how to set the color of a barchart / barchartseries in C# with openXml?

So far I have this:

```
foreach (var solidFill in barChartSeries.ChartShapeProperties.Descendants<SolidFill>().ToList())
        {
            solidFill.SchemeColor = ???
        }
```

Any idea how I can find out stuff like this myself. The documentation is really lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @wp78de I found the solution:

When you create a new chart from code you have to add all the children in the constructor call:

```
new BarChartSeries(
    new ChartShapeProperties(
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.SolidFill(
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "FFA9FF" }
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it like this

```
x.Descendants<SolidFill>().First().SchemeColor = new SchemeColor(){ Val = SchemeColorValues.Accent2 };
```

or that

```
x.Descendants<SolidFill>().First().RgbColorModelHex = new RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "FF0000" };
```

Comment: The Solidfill.First() is null. Seems there is no solidfill on `barChartSeries.ChartShapeProperties.Descendants<SolidFill>()`